# Ajax Call to append a div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jsp

I'm actually new to ajax and jquery, and I've started working on it only a few days ago. I have a jsp code like this :

```
    <label>Choose the type of procedure you want :</label>
    <select id="proc-type" name="proc-type">
    <option value="selection">Select</option>
    <option value="with-param">With parameters</option>
    <option value="without-param">Without parameters</option>
    </select>

    <div class="drop" id="dropdown">
    <label> Select Procedure (with parameters) : </label>
     <select id="combobox" name="combobox">
     <option>Proc1</option
      <option>Proc2</option>
       ...
       ...
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="drop" id="drop">
    <label> Select Procedure (without parameters) : </label>
     <select id="combobox2" name="combobox2">
     <option>Proc a</option
      <option>Proc b</option>
       ...
       ...
    </select>
    </div>

<div id="response"></div>
```

Now, these values are sent to a servlet and a html response is generated. The ajax call I used is :

if first dropdown changes :

```
document.getElementById("combobox").onchange = function(){
          var proc_type = document.getElementById("proc-type").value ;
          var username = document.getElementById("combo").value ;
          var proc_name1 = document.getElementById("combobox").value ;
          var proc_name2 = document.getElementById("combobox2").value ;
         console.log("before calling servlet ");
            $.ajax({
           url : "DBConnectServlet?user="+username+"&proc-type="+proc_type+"&combobox="+proc_name1+"&combobox2="+proc_name2,
           type : "GET",
           dataType:"text/html",
           success: function (data) {
               console.log("in ajax "+ data);
                  $('#response').html(data);
               }
      });
      };
```

if second dropdown changes :

```
document.getElementById("combobox2").onchange = function(){
              var proc_type = document.getElementById("proc-type").value ;
              var username = document.getElementById("combo").value ;
              var proc_name1 = document.getElementById("combobox").value ;
              var proc_name2 = document.getElementById("combobox2").value ;
             console.log("before calling servlet ");
                $.ajax({
               url : "DBConnectServlet?user="+username+"&proc-type="+proc_type+"&combobox="+proc_name1+"&combobox2="+proc_name2,
               type : "GET",
               dataType:"text/html",
               success: function(data) {
                   console.log("in ajax "+ data);
                      $('#response').html(data);
                   }
          });
          };
```

But problem is, the response is generated fine, but the div is not getting appended. Can anybody help ?
Even if there is some other way to do it, please suggest.

Comment: if you want to append the data then use `$(data).appendTo($('#response'));`

Comment: instead of `$('#response').html(data);` try `$('#response').append(data);` that will append data in div with `id=response`

Comment: did you get correct response from server ? did you see console in your browser?

Comment: @AwladLiton : Yes I could see the response in my firebug console. The problem was with the dataType. When I changed it to html instead of text/html it worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing dataType to "text" or "html".There is no "text/html" in jquery manual about ajax on dataType.Good luck.

Comment: Ya.. I got that.. It worked when I changed it to html. Thanx for the suggestion anyway.